# What is retString()?

Tags: apex, string, method

I am reviewing some old code and came accross this line:

```
List<String> segments = seg.retString();
```

`seg` has a value that's over 255 characters.

When I run this method my output is empty values. `seg.retString is equal to: (, , , , )`.

I am not finding any information on `retString()` method. It is not a custom defined method either. Has anyone seen this before?

Seq:

`filegen.CreateSegments seg =new filegen.CreateSegments(store,objects);`

filegen is the namespace for the ACHFileGenerator.cls (which is the class this method is in)
CreateSegments is another method that I am unable to find any documentation on. It is not a custom defined method. But I can assume what it does by the naming convention.

Comment: What is "seg"? A normal string? What's the version of the class?

Comment: seg is an ACH file.  It contains data for: File_Header_Record, Batch_Header_Record, Entry_Detail_Record, Batch_Control_Record, and File_Control_Record

Comment: retString() almost looks like it is trying to break up the five record types of the ACH but is not doing it successfully. It is on version 29.0

Comment: No, I mean, what is the data type of seg? There's some line above that reads `SomeType seg`, where SomeType is the information I'm looking for. Like `string seg` or something.

Comment: seg is of datatype `filegen.CreateSegments`. I updated the question with this info.

Comment: Do you have any managed or unmanaged packages installed which might be used in code?

Comment: Sorry, that's definitely custom. Check Setup > Installed Packages; you should have one with a "managed namespace" of "filegen". You'll need to contact the developer if you need more information.

Comment: ahh you are right. And when I go to the managed package I can see the component `CreateSegments` and when I open that up, I can see the method `retString()`. Thank you!! Do you want to post the answer and I can mark it correct?